# How can adding a parameter to an attribute influence a check constraint for other attributes?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a given table model

```
class Alarm(UuidModel, ETagModel, JsonReadModel, Queryable, JsonWriteSpecificModel):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_alarm'
    .
    .
    .
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)
    deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    notification_delay = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    .
    .
    .
    __table_args__ = (db.CheckConstraint("NOT (deleted = 1 AND active = 1)", name="check_active_when_deleted"),)
```

With this given test

```
def test_deleted_when_active(self, db):
    with pytest.raises(IntegrityError):
        a = Alarm(
            condition=TimeoutCondition(
                property_uuid='d891ef94-5775-440c-9ede-be423b3e70ae',
                timeout_sec=15 * 60
            ),
            alarmtype=AlarmType.by_code('timeout'),
            deleted=True
        )
        db.session.add(a)
        db.session.commit()
```

This test works as it should, however when adding `default=0` to the `notification_delay` attribute the test doesn't raise an `IntegrityError` and therefore fails.
I have got no clue how adding a parameter to a different attribute could influence this test. No other error is raised, if I remove the line `with pytest.raises(IntegrityError):`, the test succeeds.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: `nullable=False` means that you will get an `IntegriyError` for `notification_delay` if you don't pass a value or set a default.  This would imply that there is something wrong with the check constraint - does it actually exist in the database?  What database are you using?

Comment: @snakecharmerb A missing value is set in the schema, wouldn't that handle the missing `notification_delay` value in the test above? 
```class AlarmSchema(AlarmQuerySchema, LoadModelMixin, SkipNoneMixin):
    ....
    active = ma.auto_field(missing=True)
    deleted = ma.auto_field(missing=False)
    notification_delay = ma.auto_field(missing=0)
    ...```

Comment: @snakecharmerb ?